# Prove if $R \circ R^{−1} \subseteq \mathop{\mathrm{id}}_A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

A is a random set and R, S two relations over A. I need to prove if $R \circ R^{−1} \subseteq \mathop{\mathrm{id}}A$. I struggle a lot with math, so any help is welcome.

Comment: How do you define $R^{-1}$ and $\operatorname{id}_A$?

Comment: And when you say "prove if", do you mean you are asked to determine whether it is true or false?

Comment: R−1 = {(b, a) | (a, b) ∈ R}

Comment: And what about $\operatorname{id}_A$? (And $\circ$?)

Comment: The Identity Relation on set A is the set {(x, x) | x ∈ A}.

Comment: For $R \circ R^{-1}$ see [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_of_relations) : $R \circ R^{-1} = \{ (x,z) \in A \times A \mid (\exists y \in A) \ [(x,y) \in R^{-1} \land (y,z) \in R] \}$. But $(x,y) \in R^{-1}$ **iff** $(y,x) \in R$.

Comment: Why does $S$ not occur in the statement to be proved? Also $R\circ R^{-1}\subseteq \operatorname{id}_A$ fails when $R$ is the trivial relation (which holds on all of $A^2$), whenever $A$ has more than one element.

Comment: Thus, we have that $(x,z) \in R \circ R^{-1}$ **iff** $(y,x)∈R$ and $(y,z)∈R$. But this is not enough to conclude that $x=z$: think at the relation "son of".

Answer (score 0):

Since relations aren't necessarily functions, this is false. For a counterexample, take $A = \{1, 2, 3\}$ and define $R$ on $A$ by $R = \{(2, 1), (2, 3)\}$. Then $(1, 3) \in R \circ R^{-1}$ since $(1, 2) \in R^{-1}$ and $(2, 3) \in R$, but $(1, 3) \notin \text{id}_A$.